# What is subpixel matching precision for stereo?

Tags: opencv, stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to figure out what the subpixel stereo matching precision is in stereo_image_proc (that is, how many pixels/subpixels of disparity can the stereo matching algorithm resolve). I looked at the code a bit, and I think it's 1/4-pixel, but I've also heard it's 1/8-pixel. Do you which it is (or maybe a different value altogether)? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63538/what-is-subpixel-matching-precision-for-stereo?/) by [rdbrewer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4981/rdbrewer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2013-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am pretty sure it's 1/16th pixel. In disparity.cpp of stereo_image_proc it says so explicitly:

`// OpenCV uses 16 disparities per pixel`

Best

Tim

---

Originally posted by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) with karma: 396 on 2013-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0